# session data not carrying from page to page

Tags: php, session

When a user uses the login system on my website and the credentials submitted are correct, a session and session data is set. But the sesion data is not being carried over from page to page. At the login script I printed out the session array and it showed everything was being set. But when I went to a different page with the same code that prints the session, it shows there is nothing in the session. (Yes, I am inserting `session_start()` at the beginning of every php page that needs it)

Login.php

```
<?php

require("config.php"); 

if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // This query retreives the user's information from the database using 
    // their username. 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    // The parameter values 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query against the database 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 


    $login_ok = false; 


    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row) 
    { 

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        } 

        if($check_password === $row['password']) 
        { 
            // If they do, then we flip this to true 
            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
    } 

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
    if($login_ok) 
    { 

        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']);  
        $_SESSION['USER'] = $row; 


        /* print_r($_SESSION); */

        session_write_close();
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        // Redirect the user to the index page. 
        die("Redirecting to the home page."); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        print("Login Failed."); 

        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    } 
} 
echo $message; 
?>
```

This next script checks to see if the session is set. If it isn't, it redirects the user to the login page.

```
<?php

/*** begin the session ***/
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['USER']))
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: ../login.php"); 
    exit;
} 
?>
```

Comment: `login.php` doesn't appear to be using `session_start();`

Comment: `config.php` starts the session

Comment: This is not the answer for your question, BUT, you should NEVER store in session cookie the user information. This is not secure.

Generate a random sequence, set session id to this random sequence, and then link this session id to the user data using a session table in your database.

Otherwise, will be easy to login into your system without a valid username/password, OR will be easy to get the password out from cookies stored at user computer.

Comment: @EliasSoares The user information isn't stored in the cookie. Only session ID is stored there - the user information is held on the server.

Comment: There are a LOT of reasons why your sessions might not be working. You might have cookies disabled in your browser or there might be settings in php.ini that are preventing sessions from being saved properly. The good news is that there are TONS of articles on the web about session handling in PHP. I would recommending reading a few of these (eg. http://phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html) , running some experiments of your own (eg. dumping $_COOKIE is a good place to start) and then, if you're still stuck, ask the question again with more detail about things you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `session_start();` on Login.php too.

Comment: `config.php` starts the session